# Publish a gRPCserver project from Visual studio into Docker Hub repository

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-2019, grpc, docker-repository

I build a gRPC server into Visual studio. This server I debugged by deploying it into a local Docker container. This is working great. For this, I am using following Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj", "GrpcServer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GrpcServer"
RUN dotnet build "GrpcServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GrpcServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GrpcServer.dll"]
```

Pushing the Docker image in my local repository, which I used for debugging purposes, to a remote repository for deployment doesn't really work. (I already figured that out).

As I am searching still a way to deploy, I tried following link (where I deploy to Docker Hub):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/deploy-docker-hub?view=vs-2019

Trying to deploy to Docker hub, makes the compiler stop with the next error:

```
#12 34.06 /src/GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.5.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
#12 34.06 /src/GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.5.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
#12 34.07 /src/GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 3.0.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
#12 34.07 /src/GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 3.0.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
#12 34.08 /src/GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http 3.0.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
#12 34.18   Failed to restore /src/GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj (in 32.65 sec).
#12 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj"]: exit code: 1
------
 > [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj":
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "GrpcServer/GrpcServer.csproj"]: exit code: 1
2>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am trying to do pretty default stuff. Cannot believe this is going wrong. Anybody ideas or experience on this matter? Pretty desperate to fall back on manual Docker build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VPN wasn't configured correctly. I solved this problem closing the VPN temporary.

Answer (score 0):

See [Incident: NuGet Restore Issues on Debian Family Linux Distros](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49) and [The Microsoft author signing certificate will be updated as soon as November 1st, 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/microsoft-author-signing-certificate-update/)